# split view controller update table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using Split View Controller. For master I have Navigation Controller with Table View Controller as a root view. For details I have Navigation Controller with Custom View Controller as a root view. From master I am selecting tableView row and displaying row details in details view. From details view i can edit details of this row using another View Controller with modal segue. The question is: How can I refresh tableView (master) after saving changes in details editing view (modal). When I tap save button the `-(IBAction) unwindEditRow:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue` (of details) is triggered.

Comment: Use delegate pattern.

Comment: I am really new to iOS/Objective-C programming. It is my first day ;) more detailed answer will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of ways to send messages to ViewController when particular event has happened.

**The first method:** Use delegation pattern. What is delegate?
*Delegation is a clean and simple way of connecting objects and helping them to communicate with other. In other words, delegation is a dating service for Objective-C objects.* :) There are some useful links: [Basic concepts in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html), [Writing your own custom delegate](http://enroyed.com/ios/delegation-pattern-in-objective-c-and-writing-custom-delegates/)
Here is the way of declaring your new *protocol*:

```
@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)itemHasBeenChanged:(id)edittedObject;

@end
```

In your DetailViewController declare your future delegate:

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) MasterViewController <DetailViewControllerDelegate> *delegate;
```

Implement `itemHasBeenChanged:` method in MasterViewController.m:

```
  -(void)itemHasBeenChanged:(id)edittedObject{
    //editting logic goes here
  }
```

Tell our class to implement the `DetailViewControllerDelegate` protocol so that it knows which functions are available to it by line:

```
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController <DetailViewControllerDelegate>
```

After all these steps, you can call method in your DetailViewController whenever you want by:

```
[self.delegate itemHasBeenChanged:yourObject];
```

[Here is my example code on github](https://github.com/gneil90/DelegateInSplitViewController/tree/master/master_detail_update)

**Second way**

We can use **NSNotificationCenter** as an **alternative** to custom protocols. Making custom protocols and registering methods is hard to do in a big project and NSNotificationCenter can free us from that burden. The main approach used with NSNotificationCenter is that any object can send a notification to the notification center and at the same time any other object can listen for notifications on that center.

Comment: Thank you so much. Far too kind.