# Reload UItableView after return from another UITableView

Tags: objective-c, methods, uitableview, back-button, reloaddata

I have two UITableViews. First I'm on the "first one". I press a button on "first one" and move to "second one". On "second one" I do a changes and I press Back button. But the "first one" is in the same condition as when I left it. I would like to update the "first one". So my question is: Exists a method, which is calling when I return from another ViewController/TableViewControoler with Back button and where I can call `[self.tableView reloadData]` ?

Comment: i think what you want is delegate. try searching for "implement a custom delegate".

Comment: [Check my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105827/split-view-controller-update-table-view/20107187#20107187)

Comment: just call `[self.tableView reloadData]` in `viewWillAppear`